# Auto-Resizing of NSTextView and/or NSScrollView

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, nsscrollview

I have an `NSTextView` inside an `NSView` (which is being used by a `NSPopover`, don't know if that is relevant) that I'm trying to resize automatically and programmatically (cf caption).

[image]

I have been struggling with a lot of stuff, namely :

- Looking at `NSLayoutManager` and `usedRectForTextContainer` that give me aberrant size values
  (`usedRectForTextContainer : {{0, 0}, {0.001, 28}}`)
- Modifying `NSScrollView frame`, `[NSScrollView contentView]`, `[NSScrollView documentView]`
- Getting rid of AutoLayout

I reached the point where I can resize my scollview and my Popover, but I can't get the actual height of the text inside the NSTextView.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

```
-(void)resize
{
    //Get clipView and scrollView
    NSClipView* clip = [popoverTextView superview];
    NSScrollView* scroll = [clip superview];

    //First, have an extra long contentSize and ScrollView to test everything else
    [popover setContentSize:NSMakeSize([popover contentSize].width, 200)];
    [scroll setFrame:(NSRect){
        [scroll frame].origin.x,[scroll frame].origin.y,
        [scroll frame].size.width,155
    }];



    NSLayoutManager* layout = [popoverTextView layoutManager];
    NSTextContainer* container = [popoverTextView textContainer];

    NSRect myRect = [layout usedRectForTextContainer:container]; //Broken
    //Now what ?

}
```

Comment: does this happen only the first time resize is called? i ask because usedRectForTextContainer: doesn't do any layout before it returns the rect. Is this in Mavericks?

Comment: Yes, it is on Mavericks, and no, it varies a lot (first time called, gives an OK result, and then it's height shrinks to 0.001). If you are on Github, the project is https://github.com/bertrand-caron/BCFirstLaunchTutorial if you want to try to fork it and play around with it.

Comment: would love to. thanks.

Comment: interesting project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still have no idea why I can't use `[layout usedRectForTextContainer:container]`, but I managed to get the `NSTextView`'s height by using :

```
-(void)resize
{
    //Get glyph range for boundingRectForGlyphRange:
    NSRange range = [[myTextView layoutManager] glyphRangeForTextContainer:container];

    //Finally get the height
    float textViewHeight = [[myTextView layoutManager] boundingRectForGlyphRange:range
                                       inTextContainer:container].size.height;
}
```

Comment: You can use `usedRectForTextContainer:`, it isn't broken. The problem is it doesn't layout the text, so you need to call `glyphRangeForTextContainer:` first, in order to layout the text.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some functional code that I have tested myself for swift. usedRectForTextContainer is not broken it just is set lazily. To set it i call glyphrangefortextcontainer

I found the answer here: http://stpeterandpaul.ca/tiger/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/StringHeight.html

```
    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(string: newValue as! String)
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: NSSize(width: view!.Text.frame.width, height:CGFloat.max))
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()

    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    textStorage.font = NSFont(name: "Times-Roman", size: 12)

    layoutManager.glyphRangeForTextContainer(textContainer)

    let rect = layoutManager.usedRectForTextContainer(textContainer)

    Swift.print(rect)
```

The documentation also suggest that is the the case:

[image: pic of documentation]

Comment: `text.layoutManager!.glyphRange(for: text.textContainer!)` didn't work for me; I ended up using `ensureLayout` instead as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/17373678/359640